# Delete cookie set by root domain in subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

**Root domain**
Sets a cookie that has the `domain` set to `.example.com`

**Subdomain**: `sub.example.com`
I can read the cookie from the root domain.

I have an express app, which should clear the cookie after an action. I am using `res.clearCookie('cookie-name')` function.

Am I missing something really obvious? Or we cannot delete cookies that aren't set by the subdomain.